# The possible size of two sets intersection

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, percentages

> In a group of people $60\%$ peope like chocolate and $70\%$ like strawberry. What is the percentage of people who like both chocolate and strawberry?

I know this question is very basic I don't know what I should use here and I didn't find the solution write-up. 
What is the correct way to solve the above question?

I simply used the following method which is incorrect:

$$60\% = \frac{60}{100} = 0.6$$

$$70\% = \frac{70}{100} = 0.7$$

Number of people who like both = $0.7 - 0.6 = 0.1$

$$0.1 = 0.1 × 100 = 10\%$$

Comment: There's context not given in the question. Suppose the survey was for $10$ people. Then $6$ like chocolate, $7$ like strawberry. All $6$ of the people who like chocolate could like strawberry too (thus, the answer would be $60\%$, for the $6$ people out of $10$). Alternatively, $3$ could like both, $4$ could like just strawberry, and $3$ could like just chocolate, thus yielding an answer of $30\%$.

Comment: @Eevee , The correct answer seems to be $30\%$ . But how is it possible explain please.

Comment: No, the issue is there IS no correct answer, the question is poorly framed. As I said, there are two ways in which the survey could result in different answers for this question. The only possible way $30\%$ could be the right answer is that second scenario I posed (which is the minimum overlap between the two groups), but more overlap is possible (as with my first scenario.) So unless the question wants the minimum percentage of people that could like both, there is no correct answer, thus why I say there's context not given - there's something we're not told, either by you or the question.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer , It seems that my the question lack details well i any case thanks for explaining me the context :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not enough information to solve this problem uniquely. Consider a group of $10$ people labelled $1$ through $10$.

If $1$ through $6$ like chocolate and $1$ through $7$ like strawberry then the percentage of people who like both is $60\%$.

If $1$ through $6$ like chocolate and $4$ through $10$ like strawberry then the percentage of people who like both is $30\%$.

With similar games on larger populations I'm sure we could get every percentage inbetween as well.

Comment: The correct answer is $30\%$ but explain how is it possible i couldnt really understand your answer. Sorry,

Comment: @MalikTalha I'm not trying to sound mean, but I don't see how you could not understand the answer I gave, since I wrote out the scenarios quite explicitly. If you cannot tell me more about your population, finding the precise percentage of people who like both is impossible, since there could be multiple answers. You either need to give us more information, or ask a different question like, "What is the smallest percentage of people who like both?".

Comment: I never framed the question myself just came across it during an exam MCQ and both options were given $30\%$ & $60\%$. Well it seems the examinator made a mistake. Thanks man, i understood what you are trying to say :).